# Jquery element height as attr

Tags: jquery, height, element

just fast and simple question.
Is there posibility in jquery to set attr of element as it property without each function?

Just something like:

```
$('.google-maps').attr('data-desktop-height', this.height());
```

Comment: use $(this) so it will be $('.google-maps').attr('data-desktop-height',$( this).height());

Comment: @DharaParmar in that example `$(this)` would refer to the outer scope, not a `.google-maps` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a function as the second parameter which works under the context of each element matched by the selector:

```
$('.google-maps').attr('data-desktop-height', function() {
    return $(this).height()
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so what is better for performance? using each loop or just like you show me now?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure which is better, but I do know there won't be much difference - a few milliseconds at best. If you're worried about performance to that degree you probably shouldn't be using jQuery :)

Comment: It should be ok, but a lot of loops can make some performance problems - i will check which way is better :)